# WP8 to universal App

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I have developed a Windows Phone 8 App in C# but now I want to export it for Windows Surface.

I have already export my WP 8.0 app to 8.1 but this is a Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight app that is created whereas Universal apps use WinRT (if I have well understood ...).

So, there is a easy way to convert a windows phone 8.0 app (in silverlight) to universal app to be compatible with Windows Surface ?

Comment: There is no converter, you need to create a new project and copy things over. How many changes you have to make really depends on what APIs you are using.

Comment: Okay, this is well what I thought.
There are a lot of error when I try to create an universal app with my existing windows phone 8 app, in almost all views and many custom class ... (it's a pretty big project)

Comment: In fact, there is no way to convert a Windows phone 8.x Silverlight project to WindowsRT because there is almost all my project to change whereas I use just the "base" classes ...
If I want a Universal App, I have to re-code all my project ?

Comment: it really depends on what APIs and what external components (eg. RadControls) you use. You have to look at the errors and decide for yourself, it could be that they are only miniscule syntax changes, or a showstopper due to a vital component missing.

Comment: I have succeeded to add my windows phone 8.0 project to an Universal project but I can't reuse my windows phone code as shared code ... (without a lot of change, almost all my existing code) .
In fact, I search to understood how it works but I don't understand how to properly export my project to Windows RT

Comment: Are there a way to launch a WP8 app on a Windows RT ?
I just want to find a easy way to have my WP8 app on a Windows Surface, my first question was maybe a little confused ...

Comment: I am not aware of any, but to be sure you can make a new question