# Launch WP8 app to Windows Surface

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-rt

I have developed a WP8 app and now I want export my app for Windows Surface (Windows RT).
I want to know if there are a easy way to launch a WP8 app on Windows surface 8.0 without have to develope an Universal App ?

Answer (score 0):

Universal App was made to solve your problem.  The only way I know how to run WP8 application is to install the SDK and emulator and load it on the emulator.  And, if you have that Surface RT model, the only apps that it can run are Windows Store Apps.

---

As for converting to WP8.1 Runtime (Universal), as long as you use basic controls and the program is not to complicated it is pretty easy to transfer your program over.

Comment: I have tried to convert my WP8.0 app to WP8.1 but it's a Sylverlight App and when I want to convert to Runtime I have a lot of errors (like I explain in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461407/wp8-to-universal-app?noredirect=1#comment41569389_26461407 )